# QHeaderView going out of viewport

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I'm having couple of issues while trying to make a QHeaderView for my QTableView.

1. I want QHeaderView to be resizable by the user (`Qt.ResizeMode.Interactive`) while being able to stretch its sections proportionately when the window or QTableView is being resized. I found this problem online, and managed to mostly solve it but there is still some stuttering when the resizing begins and I think there should be a better solution than mine. Currently it's done by using QTimer to stop sections from going out of the viewport. Timer is being updated every millisecond. If the update interval is bigger, sections would go out of viewport and magically teleport back when the timer is updated, so once per millisecond in my case. There's still some stuttering visible if the user is dragging sections out of the viewport by dragging their mouse faster, not so visible when the mouse is slower, but visible none the less.
2. Every section should be resizable and movable, besides the first two. The first two sections should be immovable and fixed. I managed to make them fixed and they don't seem to have an effect on resizing of the sections, but I have no idea how to make them immovable while all the other sections are movable.
3. Sections should have text eliding, which I managed to make an item delegate for, but setting it on QHeaderView seems to do absolutely nothing (`paint()` method doesn't even get called). It's probably because item delegate isn't affecting sections, if so, how can I make a delegate that does affect them?

Here's my current code (it's a bit of a mess, but hopefully you'll get the idea):

```py
import sys
import weakref
from typing import Any, Optional

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFontMetrics
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QHeaderView, QStyledItemDelegate, QStyleOptionViewItem


class MyItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def paint(self, painter: QtGui.QPainter, option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> None:
        text = index.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        # print(text)
        if text:
            elided_text = QFontMetrics(option.font).elidedText(str(text), Qt.TextElideMode.ElideRight, option.rect.width())
            painter.drawText(option.rect, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft, elided_text)


class HeaderView(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self,
                 orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation = Qt.Orientation.Horizontal,
                 parent: Optional[QtWidgets.QWidget] = None):
        super(HeaderView, self).__init__(orientation, parent)
        item_delegate = MyItemDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(item_delegate)

        self.setMinimumSectionSize(5)
        self.setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.setCascadingSectionResizes(True)
        self.setSectionsMovable(True)

        self.fixed_section_indexes = (0, 1)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.setSingleShot(True)
        timer.setTimerType(Qt.TimerType.PreciseTimer)
        timer.timeout.connect(self._update_sizes)

        resize_mode_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        resize_mode_timer.setTimerType(Qt.TimerType.PreciseTimer)
        resize_mode_timer.setSingleShot(True)
        resize_mode_timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeMode.Interactive))

        self._resize_mode_timer = weakref.proxy(resize_mode_timer)
        self._timer = weakref.proxy(timer)
        self.sectionResized.connect(self._handle_resize)

        self.setTextElideMode(Qt.TextElideMode.ElideLeft)
        self.setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)

        self.proportions = []

        self.mouse_pressed = False

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self.mouse_pressed = False
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)
        self.proportions = [self.sectionSize(i) / self.width() for i in range(self.count())]
        # print(self.mouse_pressed)

    def init_sizes(self):
        each = self.width() // self.count()
        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.resizeSection(self.logicalIndex(i), each)

    @pyqtSlot(int, int, int)
    def _handle_resize(self, logicalIndex: int, oldSize: int, newSize: int):
        self._timer.start(1)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QtGui.QResizeEvent):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        width = self.width()
        # sizes = [self.sectionSize(self.logicalIndex(i)) for i in range(self.count())]
        width_without_fixed = width - sum([self.sectionSize(i) for i in self.fixed_section_indexes])

        for i in range(self.count()):
            if not self.proportions:
                break

            if i not in self.fixed_section_indexes:
                self.resizeSection(i, int(self.proportions[i] * width_without_fixed))

        self._timer.start(1)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def _update_sizes(self):
        width = self.width()
        sizes = [self.sectionSize(self.logicalIndex(i)) for i in range(self.count())]
        # width_without_fixed = width - sum([self.sectionSize(i) for i in self.fixed_section_indexes])
        index = len(sizes) - 1
        i = 0
        while index >= 0 and sum(sizes) > width:
            i += 1
            if i > 100:
                break
            if sizes[index] > 5 and index not in self.fixed_section_indexes:  # minimum width (5)
                new_width = width - (sum(sizes) - sizes[index])
                if new_width < 5:
                    new_width = 5
                sizes[index] = new_width
            index -= 1
        for j, value in enumerate(sizes):
            self.resizeSection(self.logicalIndex(j), value)
        if not self.proportions:
            self.proportions = [self.sectionSize(i) / width for i in range(self.count())]


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[QtWidgets.QWidget] = None) -> None:
        super(Model, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__headers = ["Column A", "Column B", "Column C", "Column D", "Column E", "Column F", "Column G"]
        self.__data = []
        for i in range(10):
            row = [0, 1, 2, 3, 42222222222, 5, 6, 74444444]
            self.__data.append(row)

    def rowCount(self, index: Optional[QtCore.QModelIndex] = None) -> int:
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount(self, index: Optional[QtCore.QModelIndex] = None) -> int:
        return len(self.__headers)

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation,
                   role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole = Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole) -> Any:
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                return self.__headers[section]
            return f"{section}"
        return None

    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex,
             role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole = Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole) -> Any:
        if role in [Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole, Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole]:
            return self.__data[index.row()][index.column()]
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.resize(600, 600)
    header = HeaderView()
    view.setHorizontalHeader(header)
    model = Model()
    view.setModel(model)
    header.init_sizes()
    view.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(0, 30)
    view.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.Fixed)
    view.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(1, 30)
    view.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.Fixed)
    view.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: From the [Appearance notes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#appearance) on the QHeaderView documentation: "Note: Each header renders the data for each section itself, and does not rely on a delegate. As a result, calling a header's setItemDelegate() function will have no effect." In any case, using it for the text elision is wrong and unnecessary, as QHeaderView is a QAbstractItemView and, as such, already supports [`textElideMode()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#textElideMode-prop).

Comment: @musicmante Thanks for the lightning fast response! I've tried calling `setTextElideMode(Qt.TextElideMode.ElideRight)` on my QHeaderView in its _init_ and on its instance after initializing it, but it's still somehow unaffected.

Comment: I've just seen that you tried to add it. It works for me on Linux, but I've found [this unresolved qtbug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-96667) that says that (at least on macOS) doesn't work for left and middle elision, can you try with other elisions? In any case, [`initStyleOptionForIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qheaderview.html#initStyleOptionForIndex) is virtual on Qt6, so you may try override the option's `text` there and *force* elision.

Comment: Then, QHeaderView already has the [`firstSectionMovable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qheaderview.html#firstSectionMovable-prop) property since Qt 5.11, if you want it for the second section you should study the sources and see how it's done to implement it; note that it's not easy, especially if you want to do a *good* implementation, as you need to completely port the `mousePressEvent()` and `mouseMoveEvent()` functions to Python since QHeaderView uses an internal (private) state which is different to the standard `state()` of QAbstractItemViews.

Comment: Finally, custom resizing is not easy for QHeaderView, as there are lots of complex aspects that deal with the resize modes and internal laying out for the view. I did some research on the matter some time ago as I was trying to achieve something similar, and I almost always ended up with some glitches: I'm afraid that in order to provide *all* that, you have to override *a lot* of things, including creating functions that QHeaderView calls internally since they're not exposed to the API. It *is* doable, but it's difficult. As said above, you have to carefully and patiently study the sources.

Comment: @musicamante Well I guess I have a lot of work ahead of me then, hopefully I'll be successful in my mission. I've tried using `initStyleOptionForIndex()` and `initStyleOption` but overriding `option.text` seems to do nothing. It doen't even seem to affect section text, the only thing that does is `headerData()` QTableView's model, but I don't know how to elide the text it returns or if it's even possible because I don't have option, font nor rect there. Any ideas maybe?